# Testing a spring boot service without running @SpringBootApplication

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a spring boot commandline app:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TheApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
      public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        ...
     }
    }
```

and I'd like to test a `@Service` that `TheApplication` uses. Normally this is fine if it's an mvc app where `TheApplication` does not have any functionality but in this case it's a `CommandLineRunner` and every time I want to test a `@Service`, `run` is called, creating a problem with the tests. I need to annotate the test as the `@Service` uses `@Value` to configure itself but these annotations cause the application to start and the `run` method to be invoked.

Is there a way to run a spring boot test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AccessTokenTest {
  ...
}
```

without `TheApplication::run` being invoked?

Comment: actually, `@SpringBootTest` wakes up the context, so the `.run()` method is invoked. You're free to omit the annotation to test the component without the context though

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out it's fairly easy according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344313/prevent-application-commandlinerunner-classes-from-executing-during-junit-test).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = CommandLineRunner.class))
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestApplicationConfiguration {
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class TheTest {
  @Autowired
  TheService theService;

  ...
}
```