# Spring Boot 2: IntegrationTest should not execute CommandLineRunner impl

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

i don't get it: The `Application` code is executed during my integration tests.

Here is my `Application` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Autowired
SurveyService surveyService;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    // some useage of the autowired service (do all the stuff)
}
}
```

The `SurveyService` consume just some REST API. 
My test looks something like that:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RestClientTest({SurveyRestService.class})
@ComponentScan("com.example.app")
@TestPropertySource(properties = "uri=http://testMe.com/")
class SurveyRestServiceTest {

@Autowired 
SurveyService classUnderTest;

@Autowired
MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

private void setupMockServerAndRespond(String response) {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://testMe.com/surveys")).andRespond(withSuccess(response, APPLICATION_JSON));
}

@Test
void shouldDeserialzeAllFields() {
    setupMockServerAndRespond(VALID_JSON_ONE_ENTRY);

    List<Survey> surveys = classUnderTest.listSurveys();

    assertThat(surveys).hasSize(1);
    // ...
}
}
```

If i execute the test i always see `Hello world` (see `Application` class). Why is the `Application` code executed? It also executed, when I remote the `SpringApplication.run` call.

In production mode my App should start, execute some REST calls and than terminate. So I put all the executions in my `Application` class. But this executions should not be called in test case. How can I achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Found a solution (using Profiles), see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35098172/5012221

Answer (score 0):

add to `SurveyRestServiceTest` :

`@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)`

Comment: Thanks for reply. `Hello world` (stdout in the `Application` class) is still visible in the logs :( Therefore my production code would be executed during test.